# Windows 7 multiple RDP session isn't working

Tags: windows, rdp, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

It was working for long time and suddenly it stopped accepting multiple users.
I'm not sure how to debug the issue. termsrv.dll version is 6.1.7601.24234 and it is as same as another VM which is 2008 R2 and it has no issues with multiple users.

There was no windows updates or GPO updates. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot  it? Nothing in the even viewer related to this.

Are there any tools to check which terminal server it is pointing to?

Answer (score 3):

This is a licensing case. By default Windows 7 should not accept multiple inbound RDP conections at same time, if were, then had been cracked and license violated.

If you are aware of this violation, so, possibly Windows restored default/original dll, as should be.

Comment: How do I set the license server in windows 7? Is it a reg key? It seems our Child domain controller was license server and its IP was changed and maybe since then the multiple rdp might have broke. We have not installed Remote desktop service or GPO modification on Child domain controller.  Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: You can't set this license. When you install your Windows 7, you agree with license terms. Windows 7 not allow multiple RDP.

You need Windows Server system and Terminal Services license to multiple inbound RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RDP Wrapper](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) instead of patching the original DLL. This will keep your stuff working, is completely update-safe and the most reliable solution.